# HOw To Remove facebook page in composteC1 when run the project

Tags: c1-cms

i want to  Remove  facebook page in compositeC1 cms

whenever i am  run this application it comes with facebook, so i want to replace my own page at the palce of facebbok details

i want to replace some other page at facebook or eles i want to dislay
some blank empty page how

Answer (score 1):

Follow this discussion - http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/348539

Answer (score 1):

The content is dynamically fetched from http://c1console.composite.net/C1/StartPage.aspx - the content is downloaded indirectly by the website service you the C1 Console. You can configure it - if you edit ~/Composite/web.config you will find the URL, and you can change it. Note that your custom page would need to share certain characteristics with our start screen (page title and JavaScript communicating successful load).

It has been discussed several times before on the CodePlex forum in these threads

- http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/272600
- http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/348393
- http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/348539